# SyntaxError: The requested module 'react-popper' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, reactstrap

[click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9aDZ.png)

SyntaxError: The requested module 'react-popper' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'react-popper';
const { Manager, Popper, Reference } = pkg;

Getting this error for a next js application and i have node version 14.6.0 but it works fine on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) , it is working fine with Next.js